# In onTapDown, how to know if something or what is in this position

Tags: flame

In the scope of FlameGame, I am adding a PositionComponent(Bubble).

This PositionComponent should also be draggable, so I have added `HasDraggables` to the FlameGame scope and "Draggable" to the PositionComponent. I am mentioning draggable if there is any conflicting implementations with `onTapDown` in FlameGame.

##### # Don't add PositionComponent if there i s already one underneath the tap

But I will not add any new PositionComponent if there is already a PositionComponent at that position. I have looked in the `TapDownInfo` but did not find anything
i can use there.

Do you know how to, not to add if there is a PositionComponent already?

```
class MyGame extends FlameGame with HasCollisionDetection, TapDetector, HasDraggables {
  @override
  Future<void> onLoad() async {
    super.onLoad();
    add(ScreenHitbox());
  }

  void onTapDown(TapDownInfo info) {
    // if (no PositionComponent underneath){add(Bubble(info.eventPosition.game));}
    add(Bubble(info.eventPosition.game));
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can implement `onTapDown` in your `PositionComponent` instead, and same with the `Draggable` methods that you want to use.

When you implement the methods on the `PositionComponent` they are only called if the event is happening on top of the component. Remember to set a `size` of your `PositionComponent` and use the `GestureHitboxes` mixin if you want hitboxes to determine whether a tap was on top of the component, the latter is more advanced so I suggest you start with just setting a `size`.

In the following example a component is created that has size `(100, 100)` and for example position `(500, 500)` if you tap those coordinates, and since we set the `anchor` to center, all the taps that are within the rectangle that is spanning from `(250, 250)` to `(750, 750)` will trigger the `onTapDown` method.

Currently there is no way to know in the `FlameGame` callbacks if a component has been tapped (this will change in a future version), but you can manually keep track of it.

```dart
class MyComponent extends PositionComponent with Tappable, HasGameRef<MyGame> {
  MyComponent(Vector2 position) : 
    super(
      position: position, 
      size: Vector2(100, 100), 
      anchor: Anchor.center,
    );

  @override
  bool onTapDown(TapDownInfo event) {
    gameRef.tappedComponent = true;

    // return true if you want the event to
    // propagate to components behind this one
    return true; 
  }
}
```

And then add the component to your game when a tap is recognized:

```dart
class MyGame extends FlameGame with HasTappables {
  bool tappedComponent = false;

  @override
  void onTapDown(int pointerId, TapDownInfo info) {
    super.onTapDown(pointerId, info);
    if(!tappedComponent) {
      // Will add a component at the position that was tapped
      add(MyComponent(info.eventPosition.game));
    }
  }

  @override
  void onTapUp(int pointerId, TapUpInfo info) {
    super.onTapDown(pointerId, info);
    tappedComponent = false;
  }
}
```

Relevant docs:
https://docs.flame-engine.org/1.0.0/gesture-input.html?highlight=tappable#tappable-components

Comment: Thanks, but how would you then add the PositionComponent to FlameGame?

Comment: Updated the answer with how to add a component to the game (that is also included in the link with the docs)

Comment: Hmm, that is on onLoad but I need it to be added when tabbing in FlameGame?

Comment: Now I understand your question, I was confused with "tabbing", it's called tapping. :)
I'll update my answer!

Comment: Now it's updated, hope it makes more sense now

Comment: Thanks, that was a good idea, thoug it does not quite work. I think I will try to keep a list of active added PositionComponent and then test if any of them is within the tab.

Comment: I see there a  children list, I will try to go with that and look if any of them has any matching position and if not then add  - first thing in the morning :-) thanks again.

Comment: How come it didn't work for you, what happened?
If you only compare the positions it will almost never recognize that the tap was on top of a component, because the positions have to be exactly the same, with floating point precision.

Comment: Thanks, I have left - I will get back tomorrow.

Comment: Hi @spydon It totally worked. I must have been too tired last night, sorry. Many thanks good thinking ;-)

Comment: And this youtube gave me a good insight into the basics - thanks ;-) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=degpUrwoaRE&t=52s

Comment: Glad you got it working! :)